# gitlab-ci running mariadb service not setting MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD

Tags: docker, gitlab, mariadb, gitlab-ci

I'm pulling my hair out here, I'm trying to run a mariadb service as part of my gitlab-ci testing of a rails application. However when the test runs, mariadb isn't honouring the environment variable in the gitlab-ci.. for example..

```
services:
- name: mariadb

variables:
  # Configure mysql service (https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/)
  MYSQL_DATABASE: hello_world_test
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mysql

connect:
  image: mariadb
  script:
  - echo "SELECT 'OK';" | mysql --user=root --password="$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" --host=mariadb "$MYSQL_DATABASE"
```

I would expect mariadb to start up with the root password, however all I get is a warning that no root password was set and obviously my CI fails.

If I change mariadb to mysql everything works fine.  IF I manually start mariab

`docker run -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mysql mariadb` 
all is also well. As is using docker-compose so why is it not working inside Gitlab-CI.  my other services seem to be able to pick up the global variables and make use of them

Comment: What gitlab-runner executor are you using?

Answer (score 6):

Lots more digging around.. I've found the mariadb take some time to start up and opens a TCP port before its ready to accept connections, which seems to be an indicator to gitlab that it's ready and more on.. However mariadb is not yet ready and so the connections are failing.

I've now written a boring script to sleep 5 and keep checking the connection, holding up the CI execution until the database is ready for access.

Comment: A lot of tanks. On more than 30 issues read in Internet, anythings speaks about this possible issue. After put a sleep 10, work fine my environment CI/CD with Gitlab and MariaDB